# Rendering a list from external API in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I'm trying to render the some information that the user clicked on. The user will see a list of codes when clicked upon they just get additional information.

Lets start from the top.

So firstly I used `useState` Hook to initialize the options.
Then I fetched some data from an external API, converted the data into JSON format and updated options. I then mapped the data that was store in options each into a option tag and returned the options in a select tag. I then added an event handler to the select tag called `handleClick`. I then used filter to get the specific option. The problem is that when I am trying to display the information but it isn't display. I tried to `console.log` it and it worked perfect but when I try to display it in a list nothing comes up.

Here is my code:

```
import { useEffect,useState } from "react"

function Data() {

    //Intializing Options using the useState Hook
    const [options , setOption] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {

        //Fetching the data
        fetch('https://api.n.exchange/en/api/v1/currency/')

        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data =>
                setOption(data)
            )
    })

    function handleClick(event) {

        const selectedBase = options.filter(code =>
                code.code === event.target.value
        )
        return(

            <ul>
               {selectedBase.forEach(currency => <li>{currency.name}</li>)}
            </ul>


            )

    }

    return(
        <select onChange={handleClick}>
        <option select="true" hidden={true}>Select an Currency</option>
        {
            options.map(options =>
                <option key={options.code} value={options.code}>{options.code}</option>
            )
        }
        </select>
    )
}

export default Data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to create a state to store option selected

```
const [optionSelected, setOptionSelected] = useState(0)
```

Then modify your handle change to only just set state option selected not return the jsx, something like this:

```
function handleClick(){
 const selectedBase = options.filter(code =>
                code.code === event.target.value
        )
 setOptionSelected(selectedBase)
}
```

At the return jsx of your component the reason not showing because you are not storing the value after your choose option, modify like this:

```
<>
    <select onChange={handleClick} value={optionSelected}>
        <option select="true" hidden={true}>Select an Currency</option>
        {
            options.map(options =>
                <option key={options.code} value={options.code}>{options.code}   
        </option>
            )
        }
   </select>
   <ul>
       //your mapping data from optionSelectedState
   </ul>

</>
```

Comment: Thanks alot made me think of solving the problem in a different way.